# How to redirect to URL from flow with invocable apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, url, redirect, invocable-method

I have a flow from which I want to call a visualforcepage with some parameteres in the URL. The flow calls the invocable apex and the pagereference method but does not redirect to the url but does show the Screen test4 in the flow. What am I missing since I do not get redirected to an external URL. Why is the redirect method triggered but does not navigate to the given URL. I also do not have any exceptions.

Apex

```
public with sharing class  NavigateToUrl {

    //input details that comes to apex from flow
    public class InputParameters {

        @InvocableVariable
        public Case CaseRec;

        @InvocableVariable
        public Zuora__Subscription__c SubRec;

    }
    //output details which goes from apex to flow
    public class OutParameters {

        @InvocableVariable
        public String Test1;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String Test2;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Navigate to URL' description = 'Navigate to URL')
    public static void getInputParams(List<InputParameters> InParam) {
        system.debug('Flow Invoked');
        redirect(InParam[0].CaseRec.AccountId, InParam[0].CaseRec.id, InParam[0].CaseRec.ContactId, InParam[0].SubRec);
    }

    public static PageReference redirect(id AccountId, id CaseId, id Contactid, Zuora__Subscription__c Sub) {
        system.debug('redirect started');
        String baseUrl = string.valueOf(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl());
        String gotoUrl = baseUrl + 'apex/' + 'shop?accountid=' + AccountId + '&caseid=' + CaseId + '&contactid=' + ContactId + '&subrec=' + Sub;
        PageReference newUrl = new PageReference(gotoUrl);
        newUrl.setRedirect(true);
        return newUrl;
    }
}
```

[image: Flow]

Result screen component
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the user experience will be the as soon as the user selects a radio button and click next he has to be navigated to the URL. If this is right then we do not need the Local Action but a Screen element built using a custom Aura Component that uses lightning:availableForFlowScreens.

In the example below I show Account as a selectable radio option in Screen 1 and then open the details page of the selected Account in Screen 2. Details below

[image: Flow]
[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2- NavigatetoUrl]
Component

Design Attribute

js Controller
({invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
// Get the record ID attribute
var record = component.get("v.recordId");
var aUrl = "/"+record;

var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
    "isredirect": "true",
  "url": aUrl
});
urlEvent.fire();
}})

Comment: I added the screen element with the component. For test purposes I added a testscreen after screen "open account" the test screen is reached but still the page does not navigate to the url. Please have a look at my updated image

Comment: What is the value assigned to the RecordId? are you able to navigate to the url generated manually?

Comment: I had a typo its resolved now. Thans for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a Core Action flow component. Create a custom Aura component and map it to the Core Action and use navigatingToURL to open the VFPage from the Aura component.

A sample for reference
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5

Comment: I tried this but this needs to be triggered by tthe create record component in my case I pass a record from a subflow so no record is created and thus the aura component isnt triggered

Comment: In the documentation the following is stated: 

When the local action is executed, the flow calls the invoke method,

Comment: Yes, when an Aura Component is called via a core action the invoke method is called. You can still pass the recordId from your subflow as an attribute to Core Action and build the vfpage url in the  invoke method of the js controller using the recordId that is  passed as the attribute value

Comment: In this case the subflow returns a collection of records (didnt metion this earlier) these are presented as a selection of radiobuttons when the user selects a radio button a recorId is selected but this selection is not a "executed local action" as stated in documentation to trigger the invocable method. This is the reason I tried this with an apex action. So I think your answer is not suitable for this case. So I need to call an invocable after selection of radiobutton/recordid (screen Test)